# AT commands in embedded systems

Tags: c, parallel-processing, embedded, at-command

I am using embedded C and trying to make application for GPRS terminal. My main problem is working with AT commands. I send AT command using serial line, but if it is some network oriented command its response could take time and because of that I have a lot of waiting, while processor don`t do anything. Idea is to make this waiting to be done in same way parallel like in different thread. Does anyone have idea how to do that because my system does not support threads? 
  I had idea to use some timers, because we have interrupt which is called every 5ms, but I don't know ho many seconds I have to wait for response, and if I compare strings in interrupt to check if all message is received it could be very inefficient, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could either use interrupts, configure the serial interface to interrupt when data is available, or use an RTOS something, like [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/), to run two threads, one for the main code and the other to block and wait for the serial data.

Update: based on your comments, you say you don't know the size of the data, that's fine, in the interrupt handler check for the byte that terminates the data, this is a *simple and generic* example you should check the examples for your MCU:

```
void on_serial_char()
{     
  //disable interrupts
  disable_interrupts();

  //read byte
  byte = serial.read();

  //check if it's the terminating byte
  if (byte == END) {
      //set the flag here
      MESSAGE_COMPLETE = 1;
  }

  //add byte to buffer
  buf[length++] = byte;

  //enable interrupts
  enable_interrupts();      
}
```

And check for that flag in your main loop:

```
...
if (MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
    //process data
    ...

    //you may want to clear the flag here
    MESSAGE_COMPLETE = 0;

    //send next command
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have interrupts for serial interface, but it doesn't detect end of message it just take one character from output and put it in buffer

Comment: @viktor.radovic if you now the message size, keep a running count and when you reach that count, set a flag and handle that in the main code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don`t have that info, i just know what string could be end of message, but is it too slow to check if in buffer exists end string?

Comment: @viktor.radovic it's the same, when you read that character in the interrupt handler just set a flag something like MESSAGE_COMPLETE=1; and check for that in the main code.

Comment: @viktor.radovic you're welcome, also check the updated answer.

Comment: This code needs some sort of protection mechanism to make it interrupt-safe. Either disable interrupts while accessing the buffer, or use double buffers, or use an atomic flag. Also make sure to declare all variables shared between an interrupt and main as volatile, to protect about compiler optimization bufs.

Comment: @Lundin I meant to show the OP a simple example, in the hope that he will check the examples for his MCU, but I will update it, thanks.

Comment: I confirm with Lundin, there are many pitfalls in this solution. I would avoid to move logic into an ISR

Comment: @jeb Like I said, just an example, besides, it is a common practice to set flags in the ISR and do the actual processing in the main code. Nothing is wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call a packetHandler in each mainLoopCycle.
This handler checks if new characters are available from the serial port.

The packetHandler will build the response message bit for bit, if the message is complete (CR LF found) then it calls a messageReceive function, else it simply returns to the mainLoop.

```
int main()
{
  init();
  for (;;)
  {
     packetHandler();
  }
}

char msgBuffer[80];
int pos=0;
void packetHandler()
{
  char ch;
  while ( isCharAvailable() )
  {
    ch=getChar();
    msgBuffer[pos++] = ch;
    if ( ch == '\n' ) 
    {
       messageReceived(msgBuffer);
       pos=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution makes a lot of assumptions about the nature of the application and hardware. The problem is that you have created a tight coupling dependency between the execution time of the main loop and the serial bus baudrate. If the main program is considerably faster then the serial bus, then it is no problem. If it is slower, then you have a problem, since you might get buffer overruns.

Comment: A normal gsm module works with 9600 or 115200 baud, this shouldn't a problem for any _normnal_ cpu today. And at the other hand, the receiving data is limited, as a gsm module answers only to questions (most of the time). So a buffer overrun couldn't occur, if the serial ISR-receive buffer is big enough. And the largest _normal_ messages are ~180bytes long.

Comment: 115200 baud might very well be a problem for low-end MCUs. Besides, the OP may run a slow clock just to reduce power and/or noise, we don't know that. There are also many on-chip UART modules with limited hardware buffers on modern MCUs. Your solution would make sense if there is a receiver buffer somewhere in the background, getting filled up from an ISR, but you don't mention ISRs anywhere in your answer.

Comment: You are right, it _could_ be a problem if ... . But if you can place a gsm module you should have enough money for an adequate cpu, too. I didn't mention ISRs as the OP said in a comment that he uses ISR for serial. So this isn't the probelm, it seems more a problem of how to implement the logic and decouple it from the serial driver

Comment: Execution time of the main loop depends on its size and complexity, not only on the clock. ISR might need to interrupt the main loop several times in a single cycle, and UART buffers are typically very small (~8 or 16 bytes), so I don't see a really valid reason why you would refuse to fill your `msgBuffer` inside the interrupt instead of the main loop.

Comment: I would fill one message buffer in the ISR, the packetHandler uses an own buffer for parsing a complete message (in this case one line until CRLF)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are rather close to the hardware drivers. If so, the best way is to use DMA, if the MCU supports it, then use the flag from the DMA hardware to determine when to start parse out the received data.

The second best option is to use rx interrupts, store every received byte in a simple FIFO, such as a circular buffer, then set some flag once you have received them. One buffer for incoming data and one for the latest valid data received may be necessary.